# Python & Mysql : Select statement with variable

Tags: python, select, where-clause, mysql-python

Hi I was looking for a similar thread but couldn't find any so decided to post.
Any hint or link would be appreciated.

I'm using python 2.7 + MySQLdb, I made a sql statement but having a weird issue.

【works】

```
Val3 = 1
sql = """SELECT ValA FROM %s WHERE Val2 = %s AND Val3 = %s""" % (Val1, Val2, Val3)
```

【doesn't work】

```
Val3 = "variable"
sql = """SELECT ValA FROM %s WHERE Val2 = %s AND Val3 = %s""" % (Val1, Val2, Val3)
```

When I use text as a variable sql statement doesn't get executed.

(Note: no error message just gets treated like as if its not there)

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 11):

Add quotes:

```
sql = """SELECT ValA FROM `%s` WHERE Val2 = '%s' AND Val3 = '%s'""" % (Val1, Val2, Val3)
```

Comment: do not forget the escape quotes.